# Getting error 5630

Tags: vba

I want to send emails using mail merge from excel for selected records. If there is no email id then there is a dash sign in email id field. I'm getting a runtime error 5630:

> Run-time error ‘5630’: excel cannot merge documents that can be
>   distributed by mail or fax without a valid mail address. Choose the
>   setup button to select a mail address data field.

```
option explicit

Sub MailMergeEmail()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model
Dim StrMMSrc As String, wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, i As Long
Dim FirstRecord As Long, LastRecord As Long, DocName As String

wdApp.Visible = False
StrMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\INPUT\ABCD COMPANY.docx", _
AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
With wdDoc
  With .MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
      LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
      "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Data$`"
    For i = FirstRecord To LastRecord
      .Destination = wdSendToEmail
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
End With
.MailFormat = wdMailFormatHTML
.MailSubject = "Test"
.MailAddressFieldName = "E-MAIL ID"
.Execute Pause:=False
Next i
.MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
End With
.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MsgBox "done"
End Sub
[/code]
```